# How to filter an array based on the filtering of inner array property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, map-function

I have the following array of objects:

```
let a = [
    {
        b: [1, 11, 12],
        c: "a1"
    },
    {
        b: [2, 56, 1],
        c: "a2"
    },
    {
        b: [1, 2, 3],
        c: "a3"
    }
]
```

I want to do the simplest operation where I can return a **second array** that is a **copy** of `a` but includes only the elements whose `b` array contains at least one element greater than `10`, and for each such element, have `b` contain only the element(s) greater than `10`. So I want the output to be:

```
[
    {
        b: [11, 12],
        c: "a1"
    },
    {
        b: [56],
        c: "a2"
    }
]
```

I know I could do this naively with loops or in multiple steps using `filter()`, but I'm wondering if there's an efficient one-line solution.
Any tips?

Comment: Just to confirm, by "efficient" you mean as little code as possible?

Comment: You can do it in one line with `.filter`

Comment: As with any filter operation, the most efficient way will be O(n). How you get there doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this:

```js
let a = [{b:[1,11,12],c:"a1"},{b:[2,56,1],c:"a2"},{b:[1,2,3],c:"a3"}]

const output = a.reduce((acc, { b, c }) => {
  // filter "b" property
  const filtered = b.filter(n => n > 10);
  
  if (filtered.length)
    acc.push({ b: filtered, c });
    
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.filter()` and `.map()` to get the desired output:

```js
let a = [{
    b: [1, 11, 12],
    c: "a1"
}, {
    b: [2, 56, 1],
    c: "a2"
}, {
    b: [1, 2, 3],
    c: "a3"
}];

let b = a.filter(({ b }) => b.some(v => v > 10))
         .map(o => Object.assign({}, o, {b: o.b.filter(v => v > 10)}));

console.log(b);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I actually misread the requirement here. And you're right. I'm not even sure why you'd want to do this on one line - seems like hell to maintain when you next need to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce and filter

```js
let a = [{b: [1, 11, 12],c: "a1"},{b: [2, 56, 1],c: "a2"},{b: [1, 2, 3],c: "a3"}]


let op = a.reduce((out,{b,c})=>{
  let temp = b.filter(e => e > 10);
  if(temp.length){
    out.push( { b : temp,c })
  } 
  return out
},[])

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way too do this.

```js
let a = [
    {
        b: [1, 11, 12],
        c: "a1"
    },
    {
        b: [2, 56, 1],
        c: "a2"
    },
    {
        b: [1, 2, 3],
        c: "a3"
    }
]

var result = [];
a.forEach((item) => {
var subItem = { c:item.c, b: item.b.filter((b)=> b > 10)}
if (subItem.b.length>0)
     result.push(subItem);
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = a.map((rec)=> {rec.b.filter((bRec)=>bRec>10), rec.c}).filter((rec)=>rec.b.length == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Other great answers here. My take is :

```
var ans = a.slice().filter(item => {
    item.b = item.b.filter(s => s > 10)
  return (item.b.length > 0) ? true : false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
There are a bunch of great answers on here (I upvoted all so far). Here's what I eventually came up with though:

```
a.filter(x => x.b.some(y => y>10)).map((z) => {
    return {
        b: z.b.filter(zb => zb>10),
        c: z.c
    }
})
```

Explanation:

You take 'a', and filter it down to include only those elements for which 'b' has 'some element y such that y>10'. So at this point you would have filtered out the third element of 'a' since it does not have any elements in it's 'b' that are > 10. You now have this:

```
[
    {
        b: [1, 11, 12],
        c: "a1"
    },
    {
        b: [2, 56, 1],
        c: "a2"
    }
]
```

Next you map that new array, ie. for each element you return a new element in a new array that has the same value of 'c', and the same value of 'b' except filtered to include only those elements that are > 10. Thus you end up with:

```
[
    {
        b: [11, 12],
        c: "a1"
    },
    {
        b: [56],
        c: "a2"
    }
]
```

Thanks for all your contributions!

Answer (score 0):

Since no one mentioned it, here is one approach using nested `filters()`.

> I based this approach in the condition that if the `b` array have some element greater than 10, then the result of filtering it by the previous condition will give as result a `non-empty` array.

Also note, this do not mutate the original array, because it changes the copy of the array that filters receive.

```js
let a = [
    {b: [1, 11, 12], c: "a1"},
    {b: [2, 56, 1], c: "a2"},
    {b: [1, 2, 3], c: "a3"}
]

let res = a.filter(
    ({b}, i, arr) => (arr[i].b = b.filter(x => x > 10)) && arr[i].b.length > 0
);

console.log(res);
```